# Python Subprocess Grep

Tags: python, grep, subprocess, popen

I am trying to use the grep command in a python script using the subprocess module.

Here's what I have:

```
userid = 'foo12'
p = subprocess.Popen(['grep', "%s *.log"%userid], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

And it returns nothing.
I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong so can someone please explain. The current method that I am using that works is by adding the shell=true which makes it output the correct output but as the help pages have pointed out it is unsafe. I need help trying to make this work so that my script isn't unsafe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you're running up against two problems:

1. This call:

   ```
   p = subprocess.Popen(['grep', "%s *.log"%userid]...
   ```

   will not work as expected without `shell=True` because the list of arguments are being passed directly to `os.execvp`, which requires each item to be a single string representing an argument.  You've squished *two separate arguments* together into a single string (in other words, grep is interpreting "`foo12 *.log`" as the *pattern* to search, and not pattern+file list).

   You can fix this by saying:

   ```
   p = subprocess.Popen(['grep', userid, '*.log']...)
   ```
2. The second issue is that, again without `shell=True`, `execvp` doesn't know what you mean by `*.log` and passes it directly along to grep, without going through the shell's wildcard expansion mechanism.  If you don't want to use `shell=True`, you can instead do something like:

   ```
   import glob
   args = ['grep', userid]
   args.extend(glob.glob('*.log')
   p = subprocess.Popen(args, ...)
   ```

Answer (score 11):

Here are two tested pieces of code to model from:

```
>>> print subprocess.check_output(['grep', 'python', 'api_talk.txt'])
Discuss python API patterns
Limitations of python
Introspection in python

>>> print subprocess.check_output('grep python *.txt', shell=True)
```

Use the latter if you want the shell to do wildcard expansion for you.  When *shell* is *True*, be sure to put the whole command in a single string rather than a list of separate fields.

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming you want to grep for 'foo12' in all files that end with '.log', to get this to work with just `subprocess` you will need to change your code to the following:

```
userid = 'foo12'
p = subprocess.Popen('grep %s *.log' % userid, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

`shell=True` is necessary for the wildcard expansion, and when that option is set you need to provide a string command instead of a list.

Also, make sure when you are providing a list of arguments that each argument is a separate entry in the list, your initial code would have been equivalent to the following:

```
grep 'foo12 *.log'
```