# Try to grep with Python subprocess including quote cant find the result

Tags: python, grep, popen, subprocess

I have one file `/tmp/test.txt`

```
this is test
that is test
```

When I run

```
[test@localhost]# grep "this is" /tmp/test.txt 
this is test
```

I got the output.

When I try to run same command with [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) I didn't get the output. It also return the code `1`.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '"this is"', '/tmp/test.txt'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

print p.communicate ()
('', '')

# Command exit code.
print p.poll()
1
```

I also check the answers [Python Subprocess Grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956865/python-subprocess-grep) in this and tried `shell=True` but its not working.

I am missing to place something in subprocess to get the output, but what I dont know :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're searching for the literal pattern `"this is"`, including the quotes. Change the second element in the command list to `'this is'` rather than `'"this is"'`.

Quoted arguments are only needed when `shell=True`, in which case the shell interprets them and still passes `this is`, without quotes, to `grep`.

Answer (score 3):

With `shell=True` you need to supply the whole command as one string:

```
>>> print subprocess.check_output(["grep 'this is' /tmp/test.txt"], shell=True)
>>> this is test
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(["grep 'this is' /tmp/test.txt"], shell=True)
>>> this is test
```

It's also mentioned in the previous Q you cite.

Comment: Sorry but i have python 2.6.2 and `check_output` is newly added in 2.6.6.

Comment: The same holds for `Popen`; I've added the example.