# python exec unix command - What is the error?

Tags: python, grep, subprocess, python-2.4

I am new to python, I want to call `grep` unix command on some file with some specific switches, but not able to get the output. Seems the `*` (globbing) is creating some problem

Below is working, and gives the grep output

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call('ls')
1-intro.txt  2-data-types.txt  3-numbers-integers.txt  4-strings.txt  data-chap1.txt
0
>>> cmd = ["grep", "-i", "string", "1-intro.txt" ]
>>> subprocess.call(cmd)
strings
0
```

Problem, when I give `*` as param to grep

```
>>> cmd = ["grep", "-i", "string", "*.txt" ]
>>> subprocess.call(cmd)
grep: *.txt: No such file or directory
2
```

I replaced the `1-intro.txt` with `*.txt`. Can you please let me know, what am I doing wrong? Why isn't the 2nd part working?

Note: Python 2.4.3

Comment: See also [Python Subprocess Grep](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7956865/4279)

Comment: btw, you could use `glob.glob()`, `os.path.expanduser()`, `os.listdir('.')`, etc instead of `shell=True`